# Using Wordpress, how do I request data from another website?

Tags: html, wordpress

For example, I have an ESP8266 running a simple html web page with a "live" (minute or so refresh rate) temperature and humidity reading. I want to copy that data and log it to the main page (every ten minutes or so) giving a recent history graph.

Comment: Like what? API service? A publicly accessible JSON only page? ATOM feed? There are a billion ways. Be specific.

Comment: I'd probably go with an API, it seems the most straightforward to me

Comment: Most (actually just many, not most at all) services provide full API details, often stateless (i.e. REST). Most languages have methods to communicate with third party applications such as AJAX or cURL. Wordpress has a simple wrapper that can deal with this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get